# Can GraphQL query a third party API?

Tags: reactjs, express, graphql

I'm new to GraphQL and was curious if I could use it to query an external, third-part API for data. I have an express backend and a react frontend and I'm sending a GET request to a third party API for the price of precious metals.

The API responds with one big object that is filled with things I don't need but I still get via HTTP. For example, API is returning this:

```
{
    "gold_bid_usd_toz": "1303.58",
    "gold_ask_usd_toz": "1304.58",
    "gold_change_dollar_usd_toz": "1.23",
    "gold_change_percent_usd_toz": "0.09%",
    "gold_high_usd_toz": "1306.51",
    "gold_low_usd_toz": "1299.85",
    "gold_londonfix_am": "1320.7",
    "gold_londonfix_pm": "1319.92",
    "silver_bid_usd_toz": "16.5",
    "silver_ask_usd_toz": "16.6",
    "silver_change_dollar_usd_toz": "-0.02",
    "silver_change_percent_usd_toz": "-0.13%",
    "silver_high_usd_toz": "16.6",
    "silver_low_usd_toz": "16.46",
    "silver_londonfix": "16.6",

    ...LOTS MORE...
}
```

If I'm only interested in two of the properties, can I do something like this:

```
query {
   gold_bid_usd_toz
   silver_bid_usd_toz
}
```

Just not sure if I have to control backend data in order to use GraphQL. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can return your request response directly from a resolver as it is.

Then in a frontend query matching this resolver, get only what you asked for.

Backend:

```
rootQuery {
  resolverName: () => getThirdParty
}
```

Frontend:

```
query {
 resolverName {
   whatYouWant1
   whatYouWant2
 }
}
```

Both your query and resolver should match your graphql schema but not the third party response.